# Python: How to get group ids of one username (like id -Gn )

Tags: python, linux

`getpwname` can only get the `gid` of a `username`.

```
import pwd
myGroupId = pwd.getpwnam(username).pw_gid
```

`getgroups` can only get `groups` of the script user.

```
import os
myGroupIds = os.getgroups()
```

How can I get all `groups` of one arbitrary `username`, like the `id -Gn` command?

```
id -Gn `whoami`
```

Comment: At least I can use  
    from subprocess import check_output
    mygroups = check_output(['id', '-Gn', user]).split()

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following works assuming you are only interested in local users only, it will not work for things such as `sssd` backed by a catalog server (for instance, `ldap`).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import grp, pwd 

user = "myname"
groups = [g.gr_name for g in grp.getgrall() if user in g.gr_mem]
gid = pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_gid
groups.append(grp.getgrgid(gid).gr_name)
print groups
```

Comment: Thank you very much. @gareth-a-lloyd. It works. But I don't understand why `gid` is not listed in `groups` at the previous statement or why `user not in grp.getgrgid(pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_gid).gr_name` . And sorry, I haven't enough reputation to vote you up for now.

Comment: `grp` and `pwd` are library modules to help parse `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd`. Hence the line that gives `groups` is generated by traversing the `/etc/group` listing. The `gid` is the primary group ID for the user as given by `/etc/passwd` this `gid` is then used to lookup the group name and add it to the list.

Comment: @gareth-a-lloyd It's interesting that the `user` is not listed in it's primary group's `gr_mem` .

Comment: this only works if users are found locally in the system, not when using e.g. sssd backed by an ldap

Comment: @GarethA.Lloyd I prepended some valuable information found in the comment section to enrich your answer as it's a relatively popular answer and me and others obviously found our ways here but ended up dissapointed after troubleshooting for a while why not all group memberships are shown. Perhaps this helps future souls spend less time analyzing what's wrong. Hope I didn't intrude, but since there was no description at all in your answer I thought it might be worth adding a bit of it :)

Comment: @Torxed thats fine, people arrive at SO posts for many different reasons, an 8yr old answer was bound to need updating eventually.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the current user's groups.

```
import os, grp
[grp.getgrgid(g).gr_name for g in os.getgroups()]
```

[`os.getgroups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getgroups) returns the list of gids of the current user.

[`grp.getgrgid(g)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/grp.html#grp.getgrgid) returns details about a group

Comment: This is the best and most concise answer

Comment: Works with `sssd` via LDAP but not for `PAM` sessions for some reason. Still a good one.

Comment: Can generate a KeyError in some situations (not sure why); may want to handle that exception

Answer (score 9):

The only way I found to make this work correctly when having users non local to the system (e.g. ldap, sssd+ldap, freeIPA) without calling id in a subprocess is by calling the [`getgrouplist`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-getgrouplist/) c function (which is called by id eventually after going trough some abstractions):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import grp, pwd, os
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library('libc'))

getgrouplist = libc.getgrouplist
# 50 groups should be enough, if not, we'll repeat the request with the correct nr bellow
ngroups = 50
getgrouplist.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_uint, POINTER(c_uint * ngroups), POINTER(c_int)]
getgrouplist.restype = c_int32

grouplist = (c_uint * ngroups)()
ngrouplist = c_int(ngroups)

user = pwd.getpwuid(2540485)

ct = getgrouplist(bytes(user.pw_name, 'UTF-8'), user.pw_gid, byref(grouplist), byref(ngrouplist))

# if 50 groups was not enough this will be -1, try again
# luckily the last call put the correct number of groups in ngrouplist
if ct < 0:
    getgrouplist.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_uint, POINTER(c_uint *int(ngrouplist.value)), POINTER(c_int)]
    grouplist = (c_uint * int(ngrouplist.value))()
    ct = getgrouplist(user.pw_name, user.pw_gid, byref(grouplist), byref(ngrouplist))

for i in range(0, ct):
    gid = grouplist[i]
    print(grp.getgrgid(gid).gr_name)
```

Comment: To make this Python3 friendly, since bytes and strings are more separated and automatic encoding doesn't occur. `getgrouplist` should have a bytes string as its first argument like so: `getgrouplist(bytes(user.pw_name, 'UTF-8'), ...)`. Obviously `xrange` is `range` in Python3 as well. But that clears up any conversion issues from Python2 to Python3.

Comment: thank you @Torxed I've ported my answer to python3

Comment: On behalf of everyone who ends up here :) Cheers for updating this many years later! :)

Answer (score 4):

The result of `id -Gn` when the user belongs to one or more groups in which several group names map to the same `gid` might not be the same as the posted answer. For instance if `/etc/groups` is similar to this:

```
 % ypcat group | grep mygroup 
 mygroup:*:66485:user1,user2,user3,...
 mygroup1:*:66485:user101,user102,user103,...
 mygroup2:*:66485:user201,user202,user203,...
 ...
```

And if the user is not listed in `mygroup` but in `mygroup<n>`, `id -Gn` returns `mygroup` but the posted answer returns `mygroup<n>`.

It seems that in my environment, because UNIX groups can have hundreds or thousands of users, this is a common group management policy, although I don't know exactly what is the user limit per group and why `id -Gn` always returns `mygroup`.

Nevertheless, with the code below I got a match with `id -Gn`:

```
import pwd, grp    

def getgroups(user):
    gids = [g.gr_gid for g in grp.getgrall() if user in g.gr_mem]
    gid = pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_gid
    gids.append(grp.getgrgid(gid).gr_gid)
    return [grp.getgrgid(gid).gr_name for gid in gids]
```

Comment: To format the output: `print(*set(getgroups('user_name')))`. Note that on some systems the same group may appear multiple times. The call to `set` filters that.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.3:

```
import os
import pwd

uid = os.getuid()
user = pwd.getpwuid(uid)
gl = os.getgrouplist(user.pw_name, user.pw_gid)
print(gl)
```